# Connection (domain user) after changing server

Tags: c#, sql

I have weird problem. Recently our admin changed server we used to work with, on another one, and now we have some problem with application writen by other company some times ago. I was trying to fix problem, but I can't find any solution last few days.

There is part of code which supposed to get user from DB, it looks like this:

```
internal User GetUserByName(String username)
{
    return this.userRepository.Single(u => u.User == username);
}

public virtual T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
{
   try
   {
     return this._unityOfWork.Context.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(expr);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType());
     return null;
   }
}
```

The problem is I am getting exception looking like this:

> "Cannot open database "databasename" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\login'."

But the most weird thing is that when I compile application, and I will run it as executable it's working fine.
Can anyone give me some advice? :/

Comment: Tha application is probably reading the credentials from the config file someplace else as you intend. A little more detail on that?

Comment: oh my god... i forgot that application has config file which is ovverwriten when runned from executable file... anyway, thank you for this.